# PyCharm Code Completion for files outside project directory

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

my python application imports other python packages in other locations on the filesystem dynamically at runtime. It then calls certain functions in these packages and supplies data objects from the main application.

The issue is that coding these external packages there is no code completion in regard to the main apps code.

Because these data objects are only supplied at runtime, as are their classes (which are already imported by then main app when calling the package) the package itself cannot reference them in any way (circular import). Since the package doesnt know about the objects up until it's running, Code Completion can't suggest any methods of these objects for example either.

Is there any way for me to provide PyCharms Code Completion with a reference to the main application, so it can autocomplete my code? By this I mean suggestions for objects of the classes of my main app, autocomplete for native python packages works fine of course.

The packages are imported by dynamically adding their path to the path variable, I tried to also add them to the interpreter path, however this did not work.

Comment: So you have a main application and based on configuration you choose which paths to include for different versions of a remote package? How often do you switch between different versions of what you want to import? Multiple times a day, or more on a weekly/monthly basis?

Answer (score 1):

So if you have `main` for your main application and `foo0` and `foo1` for different versions of your remote package, if you are currently developing `foo1` what you can do is open your `main` project then **add foo1 as a context root** to main.

To add a context root: `Settings| Project: ... | Project Structure | + Add Context Root`. Then select `foo1`.

If you want to switch your development to `foo0`, you would need to remove foo1 as a context root and add foo0.